# Is it possible to combine AND() and OR() in Excel formulae?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Is there an easy way to combine `AND()` and `OR()` within Excel formulae. IE:

```
IF(OR(AND(A2="",B2=""),AND(A2="(blank)",B2="(blank)")),"BLANK","NOT BLANK")
```

Or do you need to use nesting to achieve the same end goal?

Answer (score 6):

If you're a programmer, this synax might appeal more to you:

```
=IF((A2="")*(B2="")+(A2="(blank)")*(B2="(blank)"),"BLANK","NOT BLANK")
```

If you actually need to check some arbitrarily sized range, whether it's empty (using `"(blank)`" as an alias for empty value), you might use this formula instead:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(CheckedRange,"(blank)")=COUNTA(CheckedRange),"BLANK","NOT BLANK")
```

you can easily extend the list of empty value aliases by just adding more COUNTIFS

Answer (score 1):

The formula you provided is valid and works.
Also, in the formula you posted, you are already using nesting (the AND is nested within the OR).

On a side note, the fomula will only work if both A2 and B2 are blank, or if A2 and B2 are both set to `(blank)`. A potentially better formula for what you're trying to do is AND() first then OR() like this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2="", A2="(blank)"), OR(B2="", B2="(blank)")), "BLANK", "NOT BLANK")
```

With this new formula, you would get the result `BLANK` if A2 is empty, and B2 is `(blank)`, and vice versa.